# Can I move my new leaf save file to my computer?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

so I have a very old new leaf game and I just got a emolator with the game in it already. is it posible that I can put my 3ds game on the emolator? because Im borrowing the 3ds from a friend

Answer (score -1):

https://citra-emu.org/wiki/dumping-save-data-from-a-3ds-console/ explains how to move your save data to your computer. Keep in mind your 3DS needs to be hacked to do this.

Comment: thanks. I'll ask my friend if I can hack his 3ds. (he never uses it so it may be fine)